# Override the Default Animation for AlertDialog Composable

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-alertdialog, android-animation

How can I override the animation for the AlertDialog composable? The modifier doesn't have an `animateEnterExit()`. I want a pop enter and pop exit animation instead of the default fade in/out.

Comment: You can't. The `AlertDialog` follows the material spec. If you want to modify the enter and exit animations you'll have to come up with your own implementation using `AnimatedVisibility`. But you'll also have to manually handle the content scrim

Comment: That's interesting, because the transitions that can be seen here are nothing like the default transitions of the `AlertDialog`: https://m3.material.io/styles/motion/transitions/transition-patterns#05db0212-d641-4f07-946b-245142527e1c